# Time Reparametrization Invariance in GR

Tags: general-relativity, conservation-laws, symmetry, time, gauge-invariance

I've heard that the time reparametrization invariance in GR can be thought of as a gauge symmetry. Could someone specifically explain how, while also explaining if there is any connection with the dimensions of space-time and whether (or not) such a symmetry would give rise to a conserved current?

Comment: All coordinate transformations are gauge transformations in general relativity - that's what GR is - a theory of gauged diffeomorphisms. There is no relationship to any particular dimensions and there is no conserved current - gauge symmetries do not have conservation laws.

Comment: @Prahar Thanks. Pardon me for noobish questions. But the lack of a conserved current in such a gauge theory - is it a consequence of the fact that the field here couples to nothing external to the system? For instance, electromagnetism comes with its own conserved current etc.

Comment: it is not related to that. Electromagnetism has a conserved current, because in addition to a gauge symmetry it also has a global symmetry. What I said is that there is no conserved current corresponding to a gauge symmetry. However, a gauge theory can have (and typically does have) several global symmetries and currents will exist for that.

Comment: @Prahar Ah, sure. But I thought in the modern view on gauge theories, the conserved current comes out of demanding local gauge invariance, not from the global one. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

"Symmetries" in the name gauge symmetries is a misnomer. A better name is gauge redundancy. Whenever the fields in our system are redundant, i.e. distinct field configurations correspond to the same physical configuration, we say that the system has a gauge symmetry. Arguably the most famous example of gauge symmetries are those found in the standard model. In modern terms, the physical configuration of these systems is describe by some abstract connection on a principal bundle (see lectures 21 and 22 of [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic)), which is a 1-form on the bundle. Gauge redundancies appear due to us trying to describe this connection as a field theory on spacetime, which involves replacing the 1-form on the bundle to a 1-form in spacetime $A_\mu$. In order to do this one needs to **choose** a local section of the bundle, which is the redundancy in the description. Changing the section chosen changes the 1-form in spacetime by $A_\mu\mapsto A_\mu+\partial_\mu\Lambda$ (in an Abelian theory).

However, there are many other types of gauge theories. An example is a relativistic particle in spacetime. Conceptually, the simplest form of this theory is that of a 1 dimensional submanifold of spacetime (depending on the theory one is consider one might require this submanifold to be timelike, etc..), describing the trajectory of the particle. At this stage this looks very different from a field theory, since the basic objects are submanifold. In order to put it in field theoretical terms, what we do is that we **invent** the abstract notion of a worldline, which is some 1 dimensional manifold whose existence is independent of spacetime. Then, the theory can instead be understood as one of embeddings of this manifold into spacetime, where the image of such an embedding is the trajectory the particle follows. The embeddings can now be understood as fields (which are however defined on the worldline, not on spacetime), and thus we have succeeded in describing the particle as a field theory. However, in doing so we have introduced a redundancy, namely the choice of a wordline. Since this worldline has no physical significance, the theory should be invariant under changing the chosen worldline by a diffeomorphic one. This is a point of view towards reparametrization invariance which makes it clear that it is a redundancy and, therefore, a gauge symmetry.

Comment: The specific example you quote - it's a classical relativistic particle, correct? Could you also please expand more on embeddings, or just reference to a proper reference if it's a technical term in theory of differentiable manifolds?

Comment: Yeah, it is the classical relativistic particle. You can look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding for a definition of what an embedding is.